# Nested SELECT throws an exception "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: sql, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbexception

Trying to execute the following query on northwind access database throws an exception:

```
No value given for one or more required parameters
```

My simplified query is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Orders].[OrderDate] FROM [Orders]) t 
WHERE [Orders].[CustomerID]=?
```

The exception is **only** thrown if nested SELECT is used.

**Question:** is there a way to use nested SELECT and parameters?

My code is:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _databasePath);
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * 
           FROM (SELECT [Orders].[OrderDate] FROM [Orders]) t 
           WHERE [Orders].[CustomerID]=?", conn);

com.Parameters.Add("Bla", OleDbType.WChar);
com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Comment: I think you need to select also `CustomerID` in the nested query, and then change the `where` clause to `WHERE t.CustomerID = ?`

Comment: you are right, but I've just oversimplified the query for here. Taking the where part inside of the nested select did the job. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple problems.  One, you haven't selected the CustomerID field in your subquery so you can't filter on it from the outer query. Second, you are referencing the wrong table alias in the outer query.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT [Orders].[OrderDate], [Orders].[CustomerID] FROM [Orders]) t 
WHERE t.[CustomerID]=?
```

Alternatively, you could not select the CustomerID and put your parameter in your subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT [Orders].[OrderDate] FROM [Orders] WHERE [Orders].[CustomerID]=?) t
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just simplified it to much, but I'll try your edit/alternative query

Comment: Thank you, the first approach doesn't work, looks like a kind of OleDB limitatation, but the second one did the trick.